# RSA Signature: Java to Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to write Ruby code that copies functionality of Java code that I received as a working example. I believe I got most of it, but in the end when I'm trying to verify Signature with server, I'm getting this:

```
IAM Exception: IAM-1000:Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 384
```

Here is the Java example:

```
import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
import java.security.KeyRep;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class SignatureGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SignatureGenerator generator = new SignatureGenerator();

        String consumerId = "xxxxxx";
        String priviateKeyVersion = "1";
        String privateKey = ""; // omitted for security reasons

        long intimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("consumerId: " + consumerId);
        System.out.println("intimestamp: " + intimestamp);

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("AA_CONSUMER.ID", consumerId);
        map.put("AA_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP", Long.toString(intimestamp));
        map.put("AA_SEC.KEY_VERSION", priviateKeyVersion);

        String[] array = canonicalize(map);

        String data = null;

        try {
            data = generator.generateSignature(privateKey, array[1]);
        } catch(Exception e) { }
        System.out.println("Signature: " + data);
    }
    public String generateSignature(String key, String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Signature signatureInstance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");

        ServiceKeyRep keyRep = new ServiceKeyRep(KeyRep.Type.PRIVATE, "RSA", "PKCS#8", Base64.decodeBase64(key));

        PrivateKey resolvedPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyRep.readResolve();

        signatureInstance.initSign(resolvedPrivateKey);

        byte[] bytesToSign = stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8");
        signatureInstance.update(bytesToSign);
        byte[] signatureBytes = signatureInstance.sign();

        String signatureString = Base64.encodeBase64String(signatureBytes);

        return signatureString;
    }
    protected static String[] canonicalize(Map<String, String> headersToSign) {
        StringBuffer canonicalizedStrBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer parameterNamesBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        Set<String> keySet=headersToSign.keySet();

        // Create sorted key set to enforce order on the key names
        SortedSet<String> sortedKeySet=new TreeSet<String>(keySet);
        for (String key :sortedKeySet) {
            Object val=headersToSign.get(key);
            parameterNamesBuffer.append(key.trim()).append(";");
            canonicalizedStrBuffer.append(val.toString().trim()).append("\n");
        }
        return new String[] {parameterNamesBuffer.toString(), canonicalizedStrBuffer.toString()};
    }

    class ServiceKeyRep extends KeyRep  {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7213340660431987616L;
        public ServiceKeyRep(Type type, String algorithm, String format, byte[] encoded) {
            super(type, algorithm, format, encoded);
        }
        protected Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
            return super.readResolve();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Ruby code that tries to do the same + request in the end

```
consumer_id = 'xxxxx'
key_version = '1'
private_key = '' # omitted for security
to_encrypt = {
  "AA_CONSUMER.ID" => consumer_id,
  "AA_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP" => DateTime.now.strftime('%Q'),
  "AA_SEC.KEY_VERSION" => key_version
}

names = ''
canstr = ''

# sort
sorted_keys = to_encrypt.keys.sort
sorted_keys.each do |key|
  value = to_encrypt[key]
  names += "#{key};"
  canstr += "#{value}\n"
end

final_arr = [names, canstr]
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(Base64.decode64(private_key))
signature = key.sign('SHA256', final_arr[1])
signature_string = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(signature)

headers = to_encrypt.merge("AA_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE" => signature_string)
response = Faraday.send(:get, url, {}, headers)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please show the stack trace for the error you received.

Comment: I don't have stack trace error. I'm sending GET request to API where they expect the signature to be 384 instead of 256. If I call `signature.size` I get number of 256.

Comment: *... but in the end when I'm trying to verify Signature with server...* None of the code you posted tries to verify a signature. Both the Java and Ruby code appear
 to generate signatures.

Comment: I know. The Ruby code does it in the end by using Faraday. The only point of verification is the server and that requires 384 bytes for signature.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the server expects a signature 384 bytes long, and you are sending a signature 256 bytes long.

It is possibly worth to try

```
key.sign('SHA384', final_arr[1])
```

in order for your digest to be 384 bytes.

Comment: I'm still geting the same error about ```IAM Exception: IAM-1000:Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 384

Comment: when I call signature.size it says 256 bytes

Comment: SHA384 is not 384 bytes, it's 384 bits. The size of the signature is a function of the size of the RSA modulus, not the hash function.